# How to process an infinite queue using a fixed number of workers?

Tags: javascript, async-await, iterator, queue

I am working on cache invalidation for a web app. The desired behavior is that when someone visits a profile page, that will trigger the recaching of that user's data. I want to only be running at most *k* update jobs at once.

I came up with [the following javascript](https://codepen.io/dysbulic-the-scripter/pen/WNjGXwB?editors=1010) to create an async iterator that can be blocked when awaiting input:

```js
const pipeline = {
  queue: [],
  resolve: null,
  hold: null,
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      async next() {
        while(pipeline.queue.length === 0) {
          if(pipeline.hold === null) {
            pipeline.hold = new Promise(resolve => {
              pipeline.resolve = resolve
            })
          }
          await pipeline.hold
          pipeline.hold = null
        }
        return Promise.resolve({
          done: false, value: pipeline.queue.shift()
        })
      }
    }
  },
  enqueue(id) {
    this.queue.push(id)
    const resolve = this.resolve
    this.resolve = null
    resolve?.()
  },
}
```

The code that I came up with to do the processing of the queue was modeled after [async-batch](https://github.com/sergelerator/async-batch/blob/master/src/index.ts):

```js
const next = async () => {
  await Promise.all(
    Array(5).fill(null).map(async (_, idx) => {
      for await (let id of pipeline) {
        await handler(id, idx)
      }
    })
  )
}
```

If I start out with the queue with more than *k* elements in it, all the slots are used for processing. If I start off with just one or two elements though, it only uses the first two slots.

¿Does anyone see the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is `k` in your code? I don't see any logic for pausing operation when the number of workers are all occupied.

Comment: `k` is `5` in my example. There are five Promises created each of which is processing jobs one after the other, so there are a maximum of five active at any one time.